# Django PermissionRequiredMixin restricting access to specific users

Tags: django, django-views, mixins

I hope someone can assist me, I am trying to give custom permissions to a page/view to only 1 user with specific access/permissions. I have a model that looks like this:

```py
class Book(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key = True,
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        editable=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    cover = models.ImageField(upload_to='covers/', blank=True)

    class Meta:
        permissions = [
            ('special_status', 'Can read all books'),
    ]
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('books_detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

And a view:

```py
class BooksDetailView(
    LoginRequiredMixin,
    PermissionRequiredMixin,
    DetailView):
    model = Book
    context_object_name = 'book'
    template_name = 'books/books_detail.html'
    login_url = 'account_login'
    permission_required = 'books.special_status'
```

I have given the specific user permissions via the admin console. However, any user other than admin is getting `403 Forbidden`. Can anyone tell me how to fix this or what seems to be the problem?

Comment: You can debug it like this:

`user.has_perm('books.special_status')`

Comment: Thanks Davit, all i get is False, though perhaps i am not debugging this correctly
this is what i get:



`>>> from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
>>> CustomUser = get_user_model()
>>> user = CustomUser.objects.get(username="special")
>>> user.has_perm('books.special_status')
False`

Comment: Do you add permission 'books|book|Can read all books' to specific user in Django site administration? Just found this post when searching similar issue, but my problem is code typo.